# Django unique_together custom error message

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to create a custom error message for unique_together:

```
class Recipient(models.Model):
  mobile = PhoneNumberField()
  mobile2 = PhoneNumberField()

  class Meta:
     unique_together = (("mobile", "mobile2"),)


  def unique_error_message(self, model_class, unique_check):
    print("I don't seem to run")
    if model_class == type(self) and unique_check == ('mobile', 'mobile2'):
        return 'My custom error message'
    else:
        return super(Recipient, self).unique_error_message(model_class, unique_check)
```

However my error message is not running instead I get:

**Duplicate entry '+4473192817212-+4478192817210' for key 'mobile'\"**

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you pasted seems more like an error caused by a unique constraint on the `mobile` field of the `recipient` table, indicating that at one point you had `unique=True` at one point. Check for this constraint in the database or if this is just in development, delete the database and `syncdb` again.

Comment: It doesn't seem that way, the error message is correct in stating its a Duplicate entry both values showed represent mobile and mobile2. So it looks like unique_together is working but my error message override is not fired. I'm using Django 1.6 maybe Django has changed this?

Comment: @Spike I just came back, noticed you had checked the answer as correct, but also saw your comment. Did this end up resolving your problem after-all, or is your question still awaiting an answer? If so, I have another suggestion which I could add to the answer.

Comment: I found that Django 1.6 seemed to fire a 'IntegrityError' when forcing unique_together. I'm not sure why but I ended up catching this with an exception and raised an error with a custom message. I checked the db and it seems to be forcing the correct constraints. I would still like to get to the bottom on this tho.

Comment: @Spike interesting, yeah you shouldn't have to catch an error manually. If you wouldn't mind posting the entire code (model, view, form, etc.), I'll help you debug it. Be sure to comment @ me after, so I know to come back and check.